# storing streaming data

Tags: algorithm

Assuming streaming data (i.e. 10 Million strings every 10 minutes), what would be the fast and memory efficient way of storing strings such that if two strings have exactly the same characters but in different orders, they get stored only once.

I have a solution to find if two strings satisfy this criteria, which works in O(n) time, and is based on building a frequency histogram of the characters in each string and checking whether those histograms are the same. But this wouldn't work well since each new string must be compared with ( <= 10 M) stored strings. I can assume if we store each string as a histogram, and then separate them in different blocks, based on their size, it can make things a bit more efficient, but still this can have a huge time complexity. The ideal soltion in terms of time could be to have a perfect hashing function that operates on a histogram input (string: "cacao" -> histogram: "a2:c2:o1")

Comment: Are the strings of arbitrary length, or do they have a typical length?

Comment: nothing more than 50 characters

Comment: "But this wouldn't work well since each new string must be compared with ( <= 10 M) stored strings", then it's not O(1), but O(n)

Comment: C(50,26) = 121 trillion possibilities. Would take up a wee bit of storage space for a naive approach...

Comment: Do you only need to consider 10 minute batches, or after an hour would you have 60 million strings, after a day, 1440 million... growing without limit?

Comment: Every 10M strings, I can reset.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are short enough, then comparing sorted string might be faster than comparing histograms (it is worth to check). Note that sorting is executed only once. Just place sorted string into some kind of map: hash map, tree map etc

Comment: Wouldn't this require a special hashing function? The alphabets are not limited to 26.

Comment: Why would this require a special hashing function at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that a slightly tailored version of a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would actually be what you're interested in.

Benefits:

- It takes O(m) time to look up the occurrence of a string in your trie
- It has a *worst case* performance of O(k) to insert a string
- If you wanted to keep track of a number of occurrences of specific portions, you could augment each node to increment should a terminal string be reached (so you can keep track of occurrences of terminal "thou", "thought", etc)

Drawback(s):

- **This can be memory intensive**; you'll need to store each character of each word, and the links drawn to different phrases and each word

Comment: I assume you meant sorting each string first, then searching for it in the trie? Then each node of the trie must be augmented with a bit saying if strings finishing on inner nodes are seen in the data or they are just a suffix of a string.